# Group by of two separate field with two separate count

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have user collection with following field.
- ObjectId
- Name
- Email
- userType ( Either admin or user )
- status ( Either Active or Banned )

Now, I want total number of admin and total number of active user within one query.

I'm using aggregate function.

```
user.aggregate([{
   $group:{
      _id: "$userType",
      count: { "$sum" : 1 }
   }
},{
   $group:{
      _id: "$status",
      count: { "$sum" : 1 }
   }
}])
```

I want output like this ...

```
[{
   "userType" : "admin",
   "count" : 5
},{
   "status" : "Active",
   "count" : 10
}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way is using [$facet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/) it creates two seperate aggregations, which is kind of what you want.

```
{ 
 $facet: 
   {
     userType: [ {$group: {_id: "$userType" , count: {$sum: 1}}} ],
     status: [ {$group: {_id: "$status", count: {$sum: 1} }} ],
   }
}
```

now i'm not sure exactly how your data looks likes, and how many documents you'll get post group but you can reformat these two fields using $unwind and $addFields to look the way you want.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the most *simple* form if all you are after is "separate counts" with a limited number of returned documents would be to use [`$facet`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/)

```
Model.aggregate([
  { "$facet": {
    "userType": [
      { "$group": {
        "_id": "$userType",
        "count": { "$sum": 1 }
      }}
    ],
    "status": [
      { "$group": {
        "_id": "$status",
        "count": { "$sum": 1 }
      }}
    ]
  }}
])
```

If you don't have that ( or the expected results would [exceed the 16MB BSON size limit](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/#BSON-Document-Size), which is a limitation of [`$facet`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/), and not it's intended purpose for that matter ), then you could apply different approaches, such as a bit of manipulation of the data in the aggregation pipeline:

```
Model.aggregate([
  // Adds an array for each "type"
  { "$project": {
    "_id": 0,
    "type": [ "user", "status" ],
    "userType": 1,
    "count": 1
  }},

  // Unwind the array, creating a "document copy" for each "type" entry
  { "$unwind": "$type" },

  // Group on alternating type
  { "$group": {
    "_id": {
      "type": "$type",    // optional, just lets you know which "type" it is
      "key": {
        "$cond": [{ "$eq": [ "$type", "user" ] }, "$userType", "$status" ]
      }
    },
    "count": { "$sum": 1 }
  }}
])
```

That gives a little different style of output ( and so does the [`$facet`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/) for that matter ) but the basic data is still there. The aggregation operators in use in this case go all the way back to MongoDB 2.2, so there is no version which does not support this.

If you *really must* have the output in the format specified in the question, then you can actually apply this with modern versions of MongoDB from 3.4 onwards:

```
Model.aggregate([
  // Adds an array for each "type"
  { "$project": {
    "_id": 0,
    "type": [ "userType", "status" ],
    // optionally using $const if you really need to be compatible
    // "type": { "$const": [ "userType", "status" ] }, 
    "userType": 1,
    "count": 1
  }},

  // Unwind the array, creating a "document copy" for each "type" entry
  { "$unwind": "$type" },

  // Group on alternating type
  { "$group": {
    "_id": {
      "k": "$type",    // optional, just lets you know which "type" it is
      "v": {
        "$cond": [{ "$eq": [ "$type", "userType" ] }, "$userType", "$status" ]
      }
    },
    "count": { "$sum": 1 }
  }},

  // Reshape the results
  { "$replaceRoot": {
    "newRoot": {
      "$mergeDocuments": [
        { "$arrayToObject": [["$_id"]] },
        { "count": "$count" }
      ]
    }
  }}
])
```

So, kind of cool, however I do like to state on a regular basis that *fancy* things like [`$replaceRoot`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/) and [`$arrayToObject`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayToObject/) which typically get used in *later* if not *the last* aggregation stage are usually better handled in client side code after the "aggregation" result is returned. And mostly since such *"transformations"* usually look *much cleaner* when done that way and it's not as if you are returning any less data by including the often *obtuse* aggregation operators in order to do so:

```
  let result = await Model.aggregate([
    { "$project": {
      "type": { "$const": [ "userType", "status" ] },
      "userType": 1,
      "status": 1
    }},
    { "$unwind": "$type" },
    { "$group": {
      "_id": {
        "k": "$type",
        "v": {
          "$cond": [{ "$eq": [ "$type", "userType" ] }, "$userType", "$status" ]
        }
      },
      "count": { "$sum": 1 }
    }},
    /*
    { "$replaceRoot": {
      "newRoot": {
        "$mergeObjects": [
          { "$arrayToObject": [["$_id"]] },
          { "count": "$count" }
        ]
      }
    }}
    */
  ]);

  result = result.map(({ _id: { k, v }, count }) => ({ [k]: v, count }) );
```

As is the [`$facet`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/) example for that matter:

```
 let result = await Model.aggregate([
    { "$facet": {
      "userType": [
        { "$group": {
          "_id": "$userType",
          "count": { "$sum": 1 }
        }},
        { "$project": {
          "_id": 0,
          "userType": "$_id",
          "count": 1
        }}
      ],
      "status": [
        { "$group": {
          "_id": "$status",
           "count": { "$sum": 1 }
        }},
        { "$project": {
          "_id": 0,
          "status": "$_id",
          "count": 1
        }}
      ]
    }},
    /*
    { "$project": {
      "results": { "$concatArrays": [ "$userType", "$status" ] }
    }},
    { "$unwind": "$results" },
    { "$replaceRoot": { "newRoot": "$results" } }
    */
  ]);

  result = [ ...result[0].userType, ...result[0].status ];
```

So bottom line is it's pretty simple to do even back to to the earliest versions of MongoDB that supported the aggregation framework in any way

---

### Full example

And a runnable demonstration:

```
const { Schema } = mongoose = require('mongoose');

const uri = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/test';
const opts = { useNewUrlParser: true };

mongoose.set('debug', true);
mongoose.set('useCreateIndex', true);
mongoose.set('useFindAndModify', false);

const modelSchema = new Schema({
  userType: { type: String, enum: [ 'admin', 'user', 'moderator' ] },
  status: { type: String, enum: [ 'active', 'closed', 'suspended' ] }
});

const Model = mongoose.model('Model', modelSchema, 'userDemo');

const log = data => console.log(JSON.stringify(data, undefined, 2));

const inputData = [
  [ "admin", "active" ],
  [ "admin", "closed" ],
  [ "user", "active" ],
  [ "user", "suspended" ],
  [ "user", "active" ],
  [ "moderator", "active" ],
  [ "user", "closed" ]
];

(async function() {

  try {
    const conn = await mongoose.connect(uri, opts);

    await Promise.all(
      Object.entries(conn.models).map(([k,m]) => m.deleteMany())
    );

    await Model.insertMany(
      inputData.map(([userType, status]) => ({ userType, status }))
    );

    // $facet example
    {
      let result = await Model.aggregate([
        { "$facet": {
          "userType": [
            { "$group": {
              "_id": "$userType",
              "count": { "$sum": 1 }
            }},
            { "$project": {
              "_id": 0,
              "userType": "$_id",
              "count": 1
            }}
          ],
          "status": [
            { "$group": {
              "_id": "$status",
               "count": { "$sum": 1 }
            }},
            { "$project": {
              "_id": 0,
              "status": "$_id",
              "count": 1
            }}
          ]
        }},
        { "$project": {
          "results": { "$concatArrays": [ "$userType", "$status" ] }
        }},
        { "$unwind": "$results" },
        { "$replaceRoot": { "newRoot": "$results" } }
      ]);

      log({ "title": "facet example", result })
    }

    // Traditional example
    {
      let result = await Model.aggregate([
        { "$project": {
          "type": { "$const": [ "userType", "status" ] },
          "userType": 1,
          "status": 1
        }},
        { "$unwind": "$type" },
        { "$group": {
          "_id": {
            "k": "$type",
            "v": {
              "$cond": [{ "$eq": [ "$type", "userType" ] }, "$userType", "$status" ]
            }
          },
          "count": { "$sum": 1 }
        }},
        { "$replaceRoot": {
          "newRoot": {
            "$mergeObjects": [
              { "$arrayToObject": [["$_id"]] },
              { "count": "$count" }
            ]
          }
        }}
      ]);

      log({ "title": "Traditional approach", result });

    }

    // And "tranforming" in the client
    {
      let result = await Model.aggregate([
        { "$project": {
          "type": { "$const": [ "userType", "status" ] },
          "userType": 1,
          "status": 1
        }},
        { "$unwind": "$type" },
        { "$group": {
          "_id": {
            "k": "$type",
            "v": {
              "$cond": [{ "$eq": [ "$type", "userType" ] }, "$userType", "$status" ]
            }
          },
          "count": { "$sum": 1 }
        }},
        /*
        { "$replaceRoot": {
          "newRoot": {
            "$mergeObjects": [
              { "$arrayToObject": [["$_id"]] },
              { "count": "$count" }
            ]
          }
        }}
        */
      ]);

      result = result.map(({ _id: { k, v }, count }) => ({ [k]: v, count }) );

      log({ "title": "Traditional approach - Client", result });
    }

    // $facet example - client
    {
      let result = await Model.aggregate([
        { "$facet": {
          "userType": [
            { "$group": {
              "_id": "$userType",
              "count": { "$sum": 1 }
            }},
            { "$project": {
              "_id": 0,
              "userType": "$_id",
              "count": 1
            }}
          ],
          "status": [
            { "$group": {
              "_id": "$status",
               "count": { "$sum": 1 }
            }},
            { "$project": {
              "_id": 0,
              "status": "$_id",
              "count": 1
            }}
          ]
        }},
        /*
        { "$project": {
          "results": { "$concatArrays": [ "$userType", "$status" ] }
        }},
        { "$unwind": "$results" },
        { "$replaceRoot": { "newRoot": "$results" } }
        */
      ]);

      result = [ ...result[0].userType, ...result[0].status ];

      log({ "title": "facet example", result })

    }

  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e)
  } finally {
    mongoose.disconnect()
  }

})()
```

And output:

```
Mongoose: userDemo.deleteMany({}, {})
Mongoose: userDemo.insertMany([ { _id: 5cc54a034dabe81496cb244d, userType: 'admin', status: 'active', __v: 0 }, { _id: 5cc54a034dabe81496cb244e, userType: 'admin', status: 'closed', __v: 0 }, { _id: 5cc54a034dabe81496cb244f, userType: 'user', status: 'active', __v: 0 }, { _id: 5cc54a034dabe81496cb2450, userType: 'user', status: 'suspended', __v: 0 }, { _id: 5cc54a034dabe81496cb2451, userType: 'user', status: 'active', __v: 0 }, { _id: 5cc54a034dabe81496cb2452, userType: 'moderator', status: 'active', __v: 0 }, { _id: 5cc54a034dabe81496cb2453, userType: 'user', status: 'closed', __v: 0 } ], {})
Mongoose: userDemo.aggregate([ { '$facet': { userType: [ { '$group': { _id: '$userType', count: { '$sum': 1 } } }, { '$project': { _id: 0, userType: '$_id', count: 1 } } ], status: [ { '$group': { _id: '$status', count: { '$sum': 1 } } }, { '$project': { _id: 0, status: '$_id', count: 1 } } ] } }, { '$project': { results: { '$concatArrays': [ '$userType', '$status' ] } } }, { '$unwind': '$results' }, { '$replaceRoot': { newRoot: '$results' } } ], {})
{
  "title": "facet example",
  "result": [
    {
      "count": 1,
      "userType": "moderator"
    },
    {
      "count": 4,
      "userType": "user"
    },
    {
      "count": 2,
      "userType": "admin"
    },
    {
      "count": 2,
      "status": "closed"
    },
    {
      "count": 1,
      "status": "suspended"
    },
    {
      "count": 4,
      "status": "active"
    }
  ]
}
Mongoose: userDemo.aggregate([ { '$project': { type: { '$const': [ 'userType', 'status' ] }, userType: 1, status: 1 } }, { '$unwind': '$type' }, { '$group': { _id: { k: '$type', v: { '$cond': [ { '$eq': [ '$type', 'userType' ] }, '$userType', '$status' ] } }, count: { '$sum': 1 } } }, { '$replaceRoot': { newRoot: { '$mergeObjects': [ { '$arrayToObject': [ [ '$_id' ] ] }, { count: '$count' } ] } } } ], {})
{
  "title": "Traditional approach",
  "result": [
    {
      "userType": "moderator",
      "count": 1
    },
    {
      "status": "suspended",
      "count": 1
    },
    {
      "status": "active",
      "count": 4
    },
    {
      "userType": "admin",
      "count": 2
    },
    {
      "userType": "user",
      "count": 4
    },
    {
      "status": "closed",
      "count": 2
    }
  ]
}
Mongoose: userDemo.aggregate([ { '$project': { type: { '$const': [ 'userType', 'status' ] }, userType: 1, status: 1 } }, { '$unwind': '$type' }, { '$group': { _id: { k: '$type', v: { '$cond': [ { '$eq': [ '$type', 'userType' ] }, '$userType', '$status' ] } }, count: { '$sum': 1 } } } ], {})
{
  "title": "Traditional approach - Client",
  "result": [
    {
      "userType": "moderator",
      "count": 1
    },
    {
      "status": "suspended",
      "count": 1
    },
    {
      "status": "active",
      "count": 4
    },
    {
      "userType": "admin",
      "count": 2
    },
    {
      "userType": "user",
      "count": 4
    },
    {
      "status": "closed",
      "count": 2
    }
  ]
}
Mongoose: userDemo.aggregate([ { '$facet': { userType: [ { '$group': { _id: '$userType', count: { '$sum': 1 } } }, { '$project': { _id: 0, userType: '$_id', count: 1 } } ], status: [ { '$group': { _id: '$status', count: { '$sum': 1 } } }, { '$project': { _id: 0, status: '$_id', count: 1 } } ] } } ], {})
{
  "title": "facet example",
  "result": [
    {
      "count": 1,
      "userType": "moderator"
    },
    {
      "count": 4,
      "userType": "user"
    },
    {
      "count": 2,
      "userType": "admin"
    },
    {
      "count": 2,
      "status": "closed"
    },
    {
      "count": 1,
      "status": "suspended"
    },
    {
      "count": 4,
      "status": "active"
    }
  ]
}
```